# Gekko Optimization Suite for Python - if3 always <0

Tags: python, gekko

I am using python 3.8.10 and gekko 1.0.1. I tried to use the model.if3 to check if variables are equal or not with an inner -model.abs3. I observed a strange behavior which I could not explain and that is why I ran the sample code from https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html (if3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = m.Param()
y = m.if3(p-4,p**2,p+1)

# solve with condition<0
p.value = 3
print(p.value)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value)

# solve with condition>=0
p.value = 5
print(p.value)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value)
```

but I got the following output:

```
3
[9.0]
5
[9.0]
```

I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded gekko 1.0.1 to gekko 1.0.2 and this resolved my problem.
Maybe there was something wrong in my cached variables or upgrading fixed that issue.

Comment: Thanks for upgrading and testing. For others who also need it, here is the upgrade command: `pip install gekko --upgrade` to get the latest version. There is one thing in the version ChangeLog that may affect this issue: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/compare/v1.0.1...v1.0.2 with how the variables are initialized.