# Gekko if3 works differet for 0 and -0

Tags: python, solver, gekko

I'm trying to use **if3** method in gekko but it's working different than in docs:

```
y = m.if3(condition,x1,x2)
    y = x1 when condition<0
    y = x2 when condition>=0
```

Please see the example below:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

p = m.Param()
y = m.if3(p,1,0)

for val, expected in [(-1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)]:
    p.value = val
    m.solve(disp=False)
    print("P=", p.value, " y=",y.value, " expected=", expected)

print()
m2 = GEKKO(remote=False)

p2 = m2.Param()
y2 = m2.if3(-p2,0,1)

for val, expected in [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0)]:
    p2.value = val
    m2.solve(disp=False)
    print("P=", p2.value, " y=",y2.value, " expected=", expected)
```

The output is: (I'm using python3.9, gekko=1.0.4)

```
P= [-1.0]  y= [1.0]  expected= 1
P= [0.0]  y= [1.0]  expected= 0
P= [1.0]  y= [0.0]  expected= 0

P= [-1.0]  y= [1.0]  expected= 1
P= [0.0]  y= [1.0]  expected= 1
P= [1.0]  y= [0.0]  expected= 0
```

For the first case, for **p=0** the solver should return 0 or am I missing something? In general, how to write in gekko the following if statement:

```
if val == 0:
    y=constant1
elif val > 0:
    y=constant2
```

I've found similar question ([Gekko Optimization Suite for Python - if3 always <0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381444/gekko-optimization-suite-for-python-if3-always-0)) but upgrading the gekko version didn't help.
Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching that error in the [documentation of if3()](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=if3#logical-functions). The documentation has been updated to be consistent with the algorithm behavior. At the transition point, the solution may be `x1` or `x2` for the `if3()` function. For the `if2()` function (MPCC form), the solution at the transition point may also be a linear combination of the two values. Gekko computes a numerical solution with a solver tolerance that is [1e-6 by default](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/global.html?highlight=rtol#rtol-1). Setting the solver tolerance tighter will help to improve the resolution at the transition point.

```py
m.options.RTOL=1e-8
m.options.OTOL=1e-8
```

The `m.if3()` transition point can be shifted to avoid the issues with the 0 value. One common strategy is to shift the transition to the left `m.if3(x-0.1)` or to the right `m.if3(x+0.1)` by a small amount, especially for mixed integer problems where `x=0` has a desired output. For example, the energy usage of a pump may be something like:

```py
energy = 2e-5*voltage**2 + 0.5*voltage + 3.0
pump_energy = m.if3(voltage-0.1,0,energy)
```

This ensures that the pump reports no energy use when the voltage is below 0.1.

Comment: But if we switch the transition point, then the same problem occurs at the new point right? For example for **x=0.1  m.if3(x-0.1, a, b)** could be a or b?
I understand the root cause for it, just don't know how to proceed with my problem where transition point is crucial. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: That is correct. Numerical solutions always have a tolerance such as 1e-6 where that difference is considered within the acceptable limit to also count as a solution.